# What is the FlexibleContexts extension good for? Could you please explain it using a simple example?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was trying to understand what the FlexibleContexts extension is doing by searching for web pages that would explain it to mere mortals (people who have read LYHFGG, for example, like me) but I did not find any such resource.

**Therefore** I ask the experts on the topic: Could you please explain what this extension does, why it exists, and give one or two simple examples how and why one should use it?

**Furthermore**, If I am reading someone else's code [which](https://github.com/ryantrinkle/reflex/blob/develop/test/Reflex/Test/CrossImpl.hs) uses this extension, then what should I know about the extension in order to understand the code written using this extension?

Comment: [Here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-rules) is the relevant section in the ghc user guide. Flexible contexts allows class instance contexts to be something other than `C0 a0, C1 a1 ... Cn an`, where `C` is a class and `a` is a type variable mentioned in the instance head. It exists because sometimes very complex constraints are needed to properly express your program logic - this is essentially the motivation behind *all* typechecker extensions.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Without `FlexibleContexts` all typeclass constraints on function definitions must have type variables. For example:

```
add :: Num a => a -> a -> a 
add = (+)
```

Where `a` is the type variable. With `FlexibleContexts` enabled you can have any type inside a typeclass.

```
intAdd :: Num Int => Int -> Int -> Int 
intAdd = (+)
```

This example is pretty contrived but it is the simplest I can think of. `FlexibleContexts` is usually only used with `MultiParamTypeClasses`. Here is an example:

```
class Shower a b where
  myShow :: a -> b

doSomething :: Shower a String => a -> String
doSomething = myShow
```

Here you can see we say that we only want a `Shower a String`. Without `FlexibleContexts` `String` would have to be a type variable instead of a concrete type.

Comment: I found the `Show` instance for the [Free monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-3.2/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) quite a good example of this extension's uses.

Comment: So why is this apparently useful feature not enabled by default?

Comment: It isn't part of the Haskell standard so it isn't enabled by default. It is a GHC specific extension.

Answer (score 9):

Commonly it's used with the `MultiParamTypeClasses` extension, for example when using the `mtl` library you might write

```
doSomethingWithState :: MonadState MyState m => m ()
doSomethingWithState = do
    current <- get
    let something1 = computeSomething1 current
        something2 = computeSomething2 current something1
    put something2
```

And similarly with `MonadReader` and `MonadWriter`, along with other similar typeclasses.  Without `FlexibleContexts` you can't use this constraint.

(Note that this answer was based on [@DiegoNolan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31252435/839246) but rewritten to use an existing library that should make sense to LYAH readers).

Answer (score 7):

I've discovered a use for it apart from those mentioned: it results in clearer error messages from GHC. E.g. normally,

```
Prelude> max (1, 2) 3

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a, b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b.
              (Num (a, b), Num b, Num a, Ord b, Ord a) =>
              (a, b)
```

And with FlexibleContexts enabled:

```
Prelude> max (1, 2) 3

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num (Integer, Integer))
        arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Here's [a discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellquestions/comments/9c98hk/help_understanding_the_error_message_for_max_1_2_3/).

Answer (score 2):

`FlexibleContexts` is often used with type families. For example, when using `GHC.Generics`, it's common to see signatures like

```
foo :: (Generic a, GFoo (Rep a)) => Int -> a -> a
```

This can be seen as a variation of the `MultiParamTypeClasses` usage:

```
class (Generic a, rep ~ Rep a) => MPGeneric rep a
instance (Generic a, rep ~ Rep a) => MPGeneric rep a

mpFoo :: (MPGeneric rep a, GFoo rep) => Int -> a -> a
```

As [AJFarmar pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251163/what-is-the-flexiblecontexts-extension-good-for-could-you-please-explain-it-usi#comment50507992_31252435), `FlexibleContexts` is also useful with neither MPTCs nor type families. Here's a simple example:

```
newtype Ap f a = Ap (f a)
deriving instance Show (f a) => Show (Ap f a)
```

The alternative approach using `Show1` is significantly more awkward.

A more involved example is provided by AJFarmar's comment:

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a))
deriving instance (Show a, Show (f (Free f a))) => Show (Free f a)
```

This brings in `UndecidableInstances` as well, since it's recursive, but it does a good job of explaining just what it needs to be able to show `Free f a`. In bleeding-edge GHC Haskell, an alternative would be to use `QuantifiedConstraints`:

```
deriving instance (Show a, forall x. Show x => Show (f x)) => Show (Free f a)
```

but this is overkill because we only need to show `f` applied to `Free f a`.